# How to obtain the wave function of time-dependent coupled two harmonic oscillators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, coupled-oscillators

The form of the Hamiltonian of this system is
\begin{equation}
H = \frac{p_1^2}{2} + \frac{p_2^2}{2} + \frac{x_1^2}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\omega^2(t)x_2^2 + \frac{q}{d}x_1x_2
\end{equation}
where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are momentum operators and $x_1,x_2$ are coordinates operators, $q$ and $d$ are constants, $\omega^2(t)$ is time dependent.

So my question is how to find the wave function of this Hamiltonian,
and if it is impossible to get the wavefunction, is it possible to find its energy function?

Inspired by the comment, I find a way to diagonalize the Hamiltonian from google, anyway, I take
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&q_l = \cos\theta\cdot x_1 + \sin\theta\cdot x_2\\
&q_t = -\sin\theta\cdot x_1 + \cos\theta\cdot x_2\\
&p_l = \cos\theta\cdot p_1 + \sin\theta\cdot p_2\\
&p_t = -\sin\theta\cdot p_1 + \cos\theta\cdot p_2
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\theta(t) = \frac{1}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{2q}{d\,\omega^2(t)}\right)
\end{equation}
by this transformation, I find the new Hamiltonian $H_N$
\begin{equation}
H_N = \frac{p_l^2}{2} + \frac{p_t^2}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\Omega_l^2(t)q_l^2 + \frac{1}{2}\Omega_t^2(t)q_t^2
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\Omega_l^2(t) = \frac{\omega^2(t)-A(t)}{2}\\
&\Omega_t^2(t) = \frac{\omega^2(t)+A(t)}{2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
A(t) = \sqrt{\frac{4q^2}{d^2} + \omega^4(t)}
\end{equation}
so it seems that the Hamiltonian is diagonalized, but the two frequencies $\Omega_l^2(t),\Omega_t^2(t)$ are all dependent on $\omega^2(t)$, so actually it is still coupled and I do not know how to get its energy and wave function.

Comment: Hint : At a given time $t$, is is possible to diagonalize the Hamiltonian. To do this, first do a unitary transformation on $(x_1,x_2)$ to diagonalize the potential energy term

Comment: @SolubleFish I have edited my question and I find a way to diagonalize the Hamiltonian, I think the new diagonalized Hamiltonian is still coupled,  so can you give more details about that?

Comment: Do you know how to solve *one* HO equation with time-dependent $\omega^2$?  I only know some gaussian  solutions. The general solution is surely hard!

Comment: The system is now decoupled : you have a collection of $2$ time dependent harmonic oscillators. If you know how to solve one, you can generalize to this situation

Comment: @mike stone  I know an article solved one HO problem with time-dependent$\omega^2$, https://www-optica.inaoep.mx/ICSSUR/articulo36-2003.pdf , and you are right, it is extremely hard and complex!

Comment: @SolubleFish So the relation between the two frequencies $\Omega_t$ and $\Omega_l$ (they are all dependent on $\omega(t)$) will not influence the decoupled Hamiltonian?

Comment: Since the Hamiltonian can be written $H = H_t + H_l$, the time evolution of a pure state $|\psi\rangle = |\psi_t\rangle \otimes |\psi_l\rangle$ (ie a state whose wave function is a product of two $1$-D wave function) will be given by the the time evolution on each factor. Any state can be written as a sum of pure states.

Comment: @SolubleFish So the total energy $E_n = E_{nt}+E_{nl}$, is it correct?